# Getting modules from a zip file?

Tags: python, import, zip

There is a module I'd love to download, but it is only available in a zip file, how do I get such a file to work properly in python, so That I can import what I want?

This is in Windows 7 BTW.

Comment: Have you tried unpacking the ZIP file? Besides, Python can load modules from ZIP files provided it can find them in its path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert the whole path to the zipfile, `c:/what/ever/itis.zip`, in your `sys.path`, and `import themodule` (assuming it's at the top "level" of the zipfile's simulated directory-tree structure).

Comment: Thanks, that was a big help. Though I like exe's more.